# New Google Images Analytics Tracking

Tags: image, google-analytics

I want to track when someone clicks on 'View Original Image' on Google Images and see one of the  images I'm hosting from my domain. I prefer with Google Analytics but I can't find a way to insert Google  Analytics javascript in someway I that I can accomplish this.

The main problem is that I want let Google keep embeding the images on their Image Search Results, so the  URL still has to be a image or a image code.

I've tried redirecting with .htaccess, all the images to a PHP script that have 'image/jpeg' header and shows  the images, but it has 'image/jpeg' header so I can't insert any html or javascript code.

I've tried to redirect the images to a PHP script that have 'Location' header, but as well, I can't insert any  other code.

I've tried to echo the image code, that way the .jpg image is possible to be embedded in a  tag,  and if the person clicks on View Original Image, any additional code I insert on the bottom of the image  data, like Google Analytics javascript is executed, but nobody wants to see a lot of weird characters.

Well, I want something 'clean and easy' that don't spoil my image's positions on Google, but it's not being that easy, or maybe it's impossible to get what I want... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to track images with Google Analytics, because there's no way of inserting the Google Analytics tracking code in an image. However, many servers log the access of its files -- see Wikipedia on [server logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_log). Ask your hosting provider where you can access your log files -- often, software is provided that visualizes this data.